# Print parent name for each selection when selected multiple nodes in Tkinter tree

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tree, treeview, tkinter-layout

I want user to select multiple nodes from different branches of Tkinter Tree. So that I can do further process I should know the parent branch of each selection.

- When I select just one node I am able to get the parent id by using code below.
- When I select multiple nodes(pressing the ctrl key),I just get parent node of first selection

How can I get the parent node of all selections done simultaneously?

Here is my working code:

```
import ttk
import Tkinter as tk

def select():
    item_iid = tree.selection()[0]
    parent_iid = tree.parent(item_iid)
    node = tree.item(parent_iid)['text']
    print node

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,show="tree")#, selectmode=EXTENDED)  
tree.config(columns=("col1"))

#SUb treeview
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure("Treeview")
tree.configure(style="Treeview")

tree.insert("", "0", "item1", text="Branch1",)
tree.insert("", "1", "item2", text="Branch2")

#sub tree using item attribute to achieve that
tree.insert("item1", "1", text="FRED")
tree.insert("item1", "1", text="MAVIS")
tree.insert("item1", "1", text="BRIGHT")

tree.insert("item2", "2", text="SOME")
tree.insert("item2", "2", text="NODES")
tree.insert("item2", "2", text="HERE")

tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
tree.bind("<Return>", lambda e: select()) 

root.mainloop()
```

Current output:

[image]

Able to display parent name when selecting one node only

When done multiple selection parent of only the first one displayed, expecting parent name for each node selected.

Branch1 displayed i.e only for the first selection:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> selection()
>
> Returns a **tuple** of selected items.

[(source)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.selection) (emphasis mine)

---

`.selection()` returns a tuple of all items selected in the `Treeview`. On the first line of the function, you are explicitly only selecting the first item:

```
def select():
    item_iid = tree.selection()[0] #<---Right here you tell Python that you only want to use the first item from the tuple.
    parent_iid = tree.parent(item_iid)
    node = tree.item(parent_iid)['text']
    print node
```

Making a simple change to the function to make it loop through all elements of the tuple will resolve this:

```
def select():
    for i in tree.selection():
        item_iid = i
        parent_iid = tree.parent(item_iid)
        node = tree.item(parent_iid)['text']
        print(node)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ethan i just need one more help can I select multiple options from my tree without pressing ctrl key. I was able to do that in list box by browse mode Multiple but I am not able to do the same thing in tree view

Comment: That's a separate question. Please raise a new question if you need a new answer.

Comment: I already raised one sir I request you to look at it once, gave same code as reference (Link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58432977/11790599) Your inputs would be very helpful

Comment: You've linked to the same question?

Comment: (Link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58446788/11790599) @Ethan please find updated link here